# ROS: Rviz - publish point - subscriber - get x,y coordinates

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone

I am trying to get x,y coordinates from rviz and get it subscribed to a topic
So when i do publish point and click on any free space in rviz i get its x,y,z coordinates in the topic /clicked_point
I want to subscribe to these points and print it on the terminal.
The code i have is a simple subscriber to the topic /clicked_point.

But when i run the code i get x,y as 0.0 and not the desired coordinates that i click.

Can someone help me please in looking at my code. I suspect it has to do something with the point stamped attributes.

Please let me know

Full code

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped
import tf
import random
import numpy as np

global x,y,z
x = 0.0
y = 0.0
z = 0.0

def callback(msg): 
    point = PointStamped()
    point.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    point.header.frame_id = "/map"
    point.point.x = x 
    point.point.y = y 
    point.point.z = z
    rospy.loginfo("coordinates:x=%f y=%f" %(x,y))
        
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('goal_publisher', anonymous=True)
    rospy.point_pub = rospy.Subscriber('/clicked_point', PointStamped, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

In terminal

```
varun-flox@varunflox:~/Desktop$ ./ros_localisation_subscriber.py 
[INFO] [1607606216.839750]: coordinates:x=0.000000 y=0.000000
[INFO] [1607606221.911950]: coordinates:x=0.000000 y=0.000000
```

In another terminal with **rostopic echo /clicked_point**

```
varun-flox@varunflox:~$ rostopic echo /clicked_point 
header: 
  seq: 31
  stamp: 
    secs: 1607606021
    nsecs: 774185596
  frame_id: "map"
point: 
  x: -4.99073648453
  y: -4.93864154816
  z: -0.00288152694702
---
header: 
  seq: 32
  stamp: 
    secs: 1607606216
    nsecs: 838675541
  frame_id: "map"
point: 
  x: -4.98981332779
  y: -4.96337604523
  z: -0.0113334655762
---
```

Thanks in advaNCE

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367431/ros:-rviz---publish-point---subscriber---get-x,y-coordinates/) by [Varun](https://answers.ros.org/users/59792/varun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I mostly use a C++, but I think in Python you can write (if your def callback is a subscriber):

def callback(msg):

```
point = PointStamped()
point.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
point.header.frame_id = "/map"
point.point.x = msg.point.x         // access to point data structure and its x, y, z components
point.point.y = msg.point.y
point.point.z = msg.point.z
**rospy.loginfo("coordinates:x=%f y=%f" %(point.point.x, point.point.y))**
```

---

Originally posted by [MaximN74](https://answers.ros.org/users/37023/maximn74/) with karma: 73 on 2020-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Varun](https://answers.ros.org/users/59792/varun/) on 2020-12-10**:
Thank you it worked

**Comment by [Varun](https://answers.ros.org/users/59792/varun/) on 2020-12-10**:
NOW THAT I CAN GET THE POINTS IN THAT TOPIC
can you help me in using those coordinates to make the robot move to /cmd_vel please
Ideally to replace the manual coordinates in path_list with the x,y data from the /clicked_point for realtime waypoint setting @MaximN74

i have posted the question already here

https://answers.ros.org/question/367277/ros-subscribe-to-clicked_point-in-rviz-for-realtime-waypoint/

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-12-10**:
@Varun, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks